# Can different entities in dialogflow have the same value?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am trying to understand how to structure intents when entities contains the same strings as value.

I imagine that when adding functionalities this will become a mess;

What is the correct approach to handle this "mixed" content?

example:

**Entity 1**: content

- word document(s)
- html page(s)
- video(s)

**Entity 2**: content-specifier

- video(s)
- image(s)
- car(s)

**Example 1**: show me all [html pages] with [videos]
the expectation is to have

- @content => "html page"
- @content-specifier => "video"

**Example 2**: show me all [videos] with [cars]
the expectation is to have

- @content => "video"
- @content-specifier => "car"

Comment: Here all you need is to train the intent with possible train set with queries such as "show me all `$content` with `$content-specifier` " and in the text response for checking if its working add "showing `$content` with` $content-specifier`"

Answer (score 1):

I believe that at the beginning you're going to get a lot of false positive matches. After training and adding a lot of training phrases there it should be ok though. To help it match better the options use also a template:
[image: intent]

3 things to note here:

- make sure you correct at your intent any values it misclassified
- go at the training option frequently and make sure that the entities are correctly recognize. Make any necessary changes
- Create a template for the user input. To do so, in your intent at the training phrases, click on the quotes. It will change to an "at" symbol (@). Then add the expected format of your user's input